# Probability distributions with irregular behaviour

Tags: co.combinatorics, probability-distributions, asymptotics, applied-mathematics

Might there be a probability distribution $\mathcal{D}$ such that if we sample $a_i \sim \mathcal{D}([-N,N])$ where $[-N,N] \subset \mathbb{Z}$ then if we define the asymptotic estimate $f$:

\begin{equation}
P(\sum_{i=1}^{2n} a_i =0 ) \sim f(n)
\end{equation}

$f$ is an oscillating function? My intuition suggests that only contrived examples might exist but my intuition has been wrong in the past.

I'm particularly interested in examples that occur in applied mathematics.

Comment: If you flip a $\pm1$ coin, and $f(n)$ is the probability of a zero sum after $n$ flips, then $f(n)$ oscillates between 0 for odd $n$ and positive values for even $n$.

Comment: @MattF. Sorry, I forgot to add that this must be a sum of an even number of variables.

Comment: If you flip a coin that can be $+2$ or $-1$, and $f(n)$ is the probability of a zero sum after $n$ flips, then evenness of $n$ does not matter, but $f(n)$ oscillates between 0 if $3 \nmid n$ and positive values if $3 \mid n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the local central limit theorem (see e.g. [Esseen, Theorem 5, page 63](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485888404)), the probability in question is 
$$\sim\frac d{2s\sqrt{\pi n}}
$$
as $n\to\infty$, where $s$ is the standard deviation of the distribution $\mathcal D$, provided the following conditions: (i) the mean of that distribution is $0$; (ii) $d$ is the GCD of $S-S$, where $S$ is the support set of $\mathcal D$; and (iii) $0$ is in the support set of the distribution of $\sum_1^{2m}a_i$ for some natural $m$.

(The definition of the condition $(L_d)$ used in the mentioned theorem by Esseen is given at the bottom of page 54 of Esseen's paper.)